# GitHub REST API: Get List of Access entries on Repository

Tags: github, repository, github-api

i would like to get all added access entires (users, groups/teams, collaborators) of an repository via REST API.
This to make a overview and additional checks of users on hundreds of our repository in our organisation.

Later i would also remove automatically an user on multiple repositories and/or add groups.

I can't find any related endpoints on [GitHub RestAPI documentation](https://docs.github.com/de/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28). Is there anything or another way to get, what i would like to have?

I know how to get the information about the added teams and collaborators from the repository. Teams only deliver me the teams, not the single user or collaborators.
Collaborators deliver me all users - also these from the groups. Here i can't seen some duplicates (if one is in an team and added manually).
The results aren't what i expected.

Any informations or ideas how to get the required access datas?

Thx and best regards

Checked the documentation and searched on google for an solution. Also tried the endpoints with postman.